# Which of the following surfaces are compact and which are connected?

Tags: differential-geometry

> Which of the following surfaces are compact and which are connected?
>   The region $z>0$ in $z=xy$

$M:x^2+y^4+z^6=1$

I think the first one is neither connected nor compact, since the surface is cut into two pieces and not bounded.

What about the second one? How can I tell?

Comment: Is the first surface cut into two or four pieces? In terms of the second one, can you attempt a graph of some kind? Or maybe not a graph, but some charactistics of valid $x$, $y$, and $z$ values.

Comment: Its definitely closed and bounded so is compact. connectedness I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean $M$ is the subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $x^2+y^4+z^6=1$. It is closed (why?) and bounded (why?), hence compact. (Answers below)

For connectivity, consider first the curve $c\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $x^2+y^4=1$. We show it is connected. In any quadrant, $c$ is the graph of a function (on a connected domain), hence connected. It is easy to verify that these four connected pieces are glued to one (topological) circle, and indeed, $c$ is (path) connected.

The surface $M$ in question is a family of many copies of $c$. Every two such copies can be connected by a path, and every copy is connected. Thus $M$ is connected.

Answers to the above questions: The function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R},\;(x,y,z)\mapsto x^2+y^4+z^6,$ is continuous. The subset $\{1\}\subset\mathbb{R}$ is closed. Hence, the preimage $M=f^{-1}(1)$ is closed. If either $|x|,|y|$ or $|z|$ is greater than $1$, the equality $x^2+y^4+z^6=1$ cannot hold. Boundedness follows.

Comment: I knew that a subset in this case is compact if and only if it's closed and bounded. But your hint isn't helpful: why is it closed and bounded? How can I tell?

Comment: @pxc3110 Have a look at the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

HINT; Let $t=y^2$, $s=z^3$. Is $x^2+t^2+s^2=1$ compact (or is it connected)? Why?